# What information ASN (Autonomous Systems) router member can know about the other?

Tags: router, subnet

If I am an owner of router in Autonomous Systems (ASN), what information about other routers in AS/N routers can I know (that outsiders can not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing.

If you own an AS, you should know everything about all routers in your AS.

As far as other ASes, you can only know what the owners of the other ASes tell you, for example, the IP address to which you will connect. AS means *Autonomous* System, and that implies that you have no control of an AS which you do not own. An AS owner can set up and change his AS at will, without anyone else knowing how it is configured, except for external interfaces. How another AS is configured is really none of your business, just as how your AS is configured is not the business of anyone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ron Maupin♦! In case you are not an owner of the AS, just a member (router that is part of the AS) do you know anything about other routers that belong to AS? Does the owner share any information with the routers that are part of its AS?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You cannot be a member of an AS unless you are the AS owner (or an employee of the AS owner). Routers that belong to the AS know what other routers in the AS tell them, and that is based on how the AS owner configures the AS, which can vary wildly.